# Do I use a comma to separate "From.... to"?

Tags: prepositions, commas

At about three o'clock, the professor transitioned from the topic of communication, to the topic of political correctness.

or

At about three o'clock, the professor transitioned from the topic of communication to the topic of political correctness.

Comment: Please explain your reasons for thinking there could possibly be a comma in there. If you do not have any, then there's your answer right there. If you do have some, then we can address the actual problem with your thought process, rather than giving you a single fish.

Comment: If read aloud, there seems to be a pause whenever someone says "from some this topic, to that that other topic." So I was basing it off of intuition, I suppose. But if you say no comma, then I believe you.

Answer (score 1):

The comma is superfluous in my opinion because it breaks up the flow of the sentence more than necessary. In this case, the "to" portion still forms part of the main clause and is a vital part of the sentence.

See this rule from Purdue University's rules of comma usage:

> 4. Do not use commas to set off essential elements of the sentence, such as clauses beginning with that (relative clauses). That clauses after nouns are always essential. That clauses following a verb expressing mental action are always essential.

https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/owlprint/607/

Comment: Please do not use weasel wording. If it is plain wrong, then call it plain wrong, and not "superfluous in my opinion". Thanks.